# Angular Js data comparison

Tags: html, angularjs

How to Compare value while printing with AngularJS.

Like    {{campaignOverview.TotalMailSent | number} > 0 }

Al i want to do is to compare the Total mail sent with 0 and the print "N/A" if 0 else the value it self.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would compare the values in the controller, then use a single, simple binding

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters to your filter with the `:` symbol

```
{{campaignOverview.TotalMailSent | number:0}}
```

`number` would then be a filter that performs your formatting logic of "N/A" if zero, or otherwise self.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more. A proper syntax would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: For filters in general (the `|` indicates a filter) then the documentation on Creating a Filter (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters) is probably the best place to start.